# How do you generate a random double between these points?

Tags: python, types, double, int

```
37.807614 to 37.786996
```

The randomly generated double must have the same precision (num of digits) as those above.

For example, 37.792242 would be good, whereas 37.7823423425 would be bad.

Comment: @TIMEX: *What is best*-questions are usually subjective (I am sure you got a warning about that when posting). You could for instance show us what you have and tell us what you don't like about it. Then we can give specific advice.

Comment: This doesn't actually make sense; for example, the actual value of 37.807614 is closer to 37.7922420000000016671037883; it's simply being rounded by the formatter.  The number of digits you see in decimal is not actually a property of the underlying double.

Comment: Indeed. For the range given, all doubles have exactly the same precision. The range is a sub-range of `[32.0, 64.0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
round(random.uniform(num1, num2), 6)
```

You will occasionally get numbers that end with `...0001` or `...9999` or so due to IEEE 754 inaccuracies though.

Comment: Bear in mind that this problem is subject to floating-point arithmetic problems as described in http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html?highlight=truncate

Comment: This gets the rounding wrong at the boundaries, causing biased results.  round(random.uniform(0, 0.000010), 6)` will give 0.000000 and 0.000010 half as frequently as each value between it; the range of values that round to 0, [0,0.5), is half the size of the range of values that round to 0.000001, [0.0000005,0.0000015).

Comment: @Glenn: So then what's the correction factor that needs to be added to each endpoint?

Comment: I don't feel like sample-testing it to be sure, but probably (.1**6)/2, where 6 is the precision.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but to avoid rounding, and since you want exactly that precision, isn't it easiest to work in integers and then convert to floating point by division? I.e.

offset = float(random.randint(0,20618))
num = (offset + 37786996.0) / 1000000.0

Comment: Why 20,618? Why 37786996?

Comment: Because 20618 is the difference between the two floating point numbers the OP wanted to range between and 37786996 / 100000 is the lower bound of the range of numbers the OP wanted to range between.